# What is a good French equivalent for “least said, soonest mended”?

Tags: anglais, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, proverbes

Does anyone know a good French equivalent for "least said, soonest mended"?

Comment: Please when asking for the equivalent of idiomatic expressions from another language, explain what the expression means.

Answer (score 8):

“*Moins on en parle, mieux on se porte.*” is made of two separate idiomatic phrases and is a way to build a (quite good) French equivalent to this expression. This combination is common, and even though it might not be considered a proverb or a saying, it sounds like one.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the expression "moins de paroles, plus de résultats", meaning "less talking, more results".

Comment: AFAIK, this doesn't have the correct meaning.

Answer (score -1):

A bit aggressive :"Au travail, sans phrase !"

Comment: Vraiment? "Sans phrase" est **vraiment** bancal, à la limite "Sans un mot" serait acceptable, mais ça ne rejoind toujours pas le sens de l'expression à traduire.

Comment: C'était une allusion, que je croyais évidente, au terrible : "la mort, sans phrase" de Sieyès au procès de Louis XVI. Le mot avait aussi le sens de discours emphatique, alambiqué ; nous avons gardé "phraseur".